# Python and Kivy language communication

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am having issues understanding communication between Python and Kivy language - more concretely below.

#### The situation

I have an app - `TutorialApp` with `build` method returning `MyScreenManager()`. `MyScreenManager` manages only one screen called `FirstScreen`. In corresponding `tutorial.kv` file I give `FirstScreen` `BoxLayout` widget with `id: box`. Let's say I have a list

```
FILMS = ['Film 1', 'Film 2']
```

Now, when I run the application I would like to add a `Button` widget for each of the film to the `BoxLayout` with id `box`. This should be done only once, so I thought to put it inside `__init__` function, which I override with `super` method. This is my `main.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from kivy.app               import App
from kivy.uix.button        import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout     import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

FILMS = ['Film 1', 'Film 2']

class TutorialApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kvargs)

        for film in FILMS:
            self.ids.box.add_widget(Button(text=film))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TutorialApp().run()
```

This is my `tutorial.kv` file:

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    FirstScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'FirstScreen'
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
```

But my approach does not work. Why? Probably because at the time, when `__init__` is called there is no `BoxLayout` and there are no ids, so I can't reference to them (at least this is what I think based on the log, also tested it by printing `self.ids` on different times).

#### Different approach

Now, what I could do is the following. Instead of creating the `BoxLayout` inside `tutorial.kv` file I could simply adjust the code like this (showing only the parts that changes):

```
class FirstScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kvargs)

        box = BoxLayout(id='box')
        for film in FILMS:
            box.add_widget(Button(text=film))
        self.add_widget(box)
```

And the `tutorial.kv`:

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    FirstScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'FirstScreen'
```

This works, but then I ran into other problems. Assume I have more screens and I want to add a `Button` to my `FirstScreeen` which would lead to different screen (not specified in the example). So, the `Button` would be specified inside `tutorial.kv` like this:

```
Button:
    text: 'Go somewhere else'
    on_release: app.root.current = 'DifferentScreenName'
```

But since I created the box inside the `__init__` function I can't simply put this piece of code inside `tutorial.kv`. I can change `main.py` like this:

```
class FirstScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kvargs)

        box = BoxLayout(id='box')
        for film in FILMS:
            box.add_widget(Button(text=film))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='Go somewhere else',
                              on_release="""WHAT SHOULD GO HERE?"""))
        self.add_widget(box)
```

But as represented with the words *WHAT SHOULD GO HERE?* I don't know how to change the screen. So, hopefully you understand the problem. I don't know which way is better, I assume, the more things which specify the layout of the app are in `*.kv` file the better, but how to solve situations similar to this one?

#### My guesses


I know this is long, but I want to assure you that I have tried somethings myself.

**First guess**
Call something like `on_init/on_start` inside `tutorial.kv` for example:

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    FirstScreen:
    DifferentScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'FirstScreen'
    BoxLayout:
        id:box
        on_start: root.method_which_adds_film_buttons
        Button:
            text: 'Go somewhere else'
            on_release: app.root.current ='DifferentScreen'
```

Hoping, that such method would run only once, when `FirstScreen` is initialized. But I could not find a method like that.

**Second guess**

Adjust the `__init__` function like this:
    class FirstScreen(Screen):

```
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kvargs)

        box = BoxLayout(id='box')
        for film in FILMS:
            box.add_widget(Button(text=film))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='Go somewhere else',
                              on_release=app.root.current('DifferentScreen')))
        self.add_widget(box)
```

Or this:

```
class FirstScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kvargs)

        box = BoxLayout(id='box')
        for film in FILMS:
            box.add_widget(Button(text=film))
        box.add_widget(Button(text='Go somewhere else',
                              on_release=self.root.current('DifferentScreen')))
        self.add_widget(box)
```

Neither does obviously work (that's why I am asking here). Both those examples show, that I do not understand how `root` is passed around. Can somebody explain/give working example of the behaviour I am looking for?

Comment: Thanks to Kivy IRC user <dessant> I got the following answer, which does the trick: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cdac178934b73eae51e0

Comment: Please paste the link into an answer and mark as solved so it won't appear among unsolved questions. TNX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kivy IRC user  I got the following answer, which does the trick: gist.github.com/anonymous/cdac178934b73eae51e0